# Get the sum of child's tables fields in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have table scheme as below:

Table A:

```
id  field_a1:integer   
1  100
```

Table B

```
 id  a1_id:integer  field_b1   
 1   1              201        
 2   1              202
```

Table C

```
id  a1_id:integer  field_c1   
1   1              200
```

I need sql query to get the SUM of Table A and B fields
so result should be as bellow

SQL results(should be):

```
table_A_field_a1   total_sum(field_c1+field_b1)
100                603(200+201+202)
```

my sql query is

```
SELECT (SUM(field_c1)+SUM(field_b1)) total_sum, a1.* 
FROM A as a 
LEFT JOIN B as b on b.a1_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN C as c on c.a1_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

But i am getting total_sum = 803 but it should be 603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL**:

```
SELECT a.field_a,
       ( b_agg.field_b1_total + c_agg.field_c1_total ) total_sum
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a1_id,
                               Sum(field_b1) field_b1_total
                        FROM   b
                        GROUP  BY a1_id) b_agg
                    ON a.id = b_agg.a1_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a1_id,
                               Sum(field_c1) field_c1_total
                        FROM   c
                        GROUP  BY a1_id) c_agg
                    ON a.id = c_agg.a1_id;
```

**Output**:

```
 field_a | total_sum
---------+-----------
     100 |       603
(1 row)
```

**Tables**:

```
create table a(id int, field_a int);
insert into a values(1,100);

create table b(id int, a1_id int, field_b1 int);
insert into b values(1,1,201);
insert into b values(2,1,202);

create table c(id int, a1_id int, field_c1 int);
insert into c values(1,1,200);

postgres=# select * from a;
 id | field_a
----+---------
  1 |     100
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from b;
 id | a1_id | field_b1
----+-------+----------
  1 |     1 |      201
  2 |     1 |      202
(2 rows)

postgres=# select * from c;
 id | a1_id | field_c1
----+-------+----------
  1 |     1 |      200
(1 row)
```

**Edit** : 2nd February 2022 - Making the query more performant

1. Since you have three tables , there is a need to access all three tables at least once , you can at best improve the access pattern.
2. Since you are outer joining on table A , you can materialize your needed data from table A in a CTE or TEMP table -- say for specific ID range
3. You can use the ID's that you get in the CTE in A to filter rows in B  and then run the aggregate on B.
4. You can do the same with C , use the ID  from the CTE on A.
5. If you have too many ID's from table A to be used in this SQL , then you will need to run this SQL for multiple ranges of ID's.
6. Indexes on A.id , B.a1_id and C.a1_id would help.

**Goal**:

- Is to execute group by on less data.
- Avoid full table scans on the 15 million rows table which I assume its table A as its the table you are outer joining to.

**SQL**: (  **Divide & Conquer** Run this sql by changing the range --- id BETWEEN 1 AND 100 , then 101-200, 201-300 , determine the range by testing and checking what is an acceptable response time , you might like to use pg_stat_statement or explain plan to get the right range for which there is no temp usage.).

```
WITH a_cte
     AS (SELECT a.field_a,
                a.id
         FROM   a
         WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 100),
     b_cte_agg
     AS (SELECT a1_id,
                Sum(field_b1) field_b1_total
         FROM   b
         WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
                          FROM   a_cte) 
         GROUP  BY a1_id),
     c_cte_agg
     AS (SELECT a1_id,
                Sum(field_c1) field_c1_total
         FROM   c
         WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
                          FROM   a_cte) 
         GROUP  BY a1_id)
SELECT a_cte.field_a,
       ( b_cte_agg.field_b1_total
         + c_cte_agg.field_c1_total ) total_sum
FROM   a_cte
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b_cte_agg
                    ON a_cte.id = b_cte_agg.a1_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN c_cte_agg 
                    ON a_cte.id = c_cte_agg.a1_id;
```

**Tested**:

```
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# WITH a_cte
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a.field_a,
postgres(#                 a.id
postgres(#          FROM   a
postgres(#          WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 100),
postgres-#      b_cte_agg
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a1_id,
postgres(#                 Sum(field_b1) field_b1_total
postgres(#          FROM   b
postgres(#          WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
postgres(#                           FROM   a_cte)
postgres(#          GROUP  BY a1_id),
postgres-#      c_cte_agg
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a1_id,
postgres(#                 Sum(field_c1) field_c1_total
postgres(#          FROM   c
postgres(#          WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
postgres(#                           FROM   a_cte)
postgres(#          GROUP  BY a1_id)
postgres-# SELECT a_cte.field_a,
postgres-#        ( b_cte_agg.field_b1_total
postgres(#          + c_cte_agg.field_c1_total ) total_sum
postgres-# FROM   a_cte
postgres-#        LEFT OUTER JOIN b_cte_agg
postgres-#                     ON a_cte.id = b_cte_agg.a1_id
postgres-#        LEFT OUTER JOIN c_cte_agg
postgres-#                     ON a_cte.id = c_cte_agg.a1_id;
 field_a | total_sum
---------+-----------
     100 |       603
(1 row)
```

**Retain Data from Multiple Iterations**

To capture the data , you can define a temporary table and store the data for each iteration.
For example:

```
create temp table finaldata(field_a int , total_sum int);
postgres=# create temp table finaldata(field_a int , total_sum int);
CREATE TABLE
```

Then repeat this for all the ID ranges from table A.

```
postgres=# WITH a_cte
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a.field_a,
postgres(#                 a.id
postgres(#          FROM   a
postgres(#          WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 100),
postgres-#      b_cte_agg
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a1_id,
postgres(#                 Sum(field_b1) field_b1_total
postgres(#          FROM   b
postgres(#          WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
postgres(#                           FROM   a_cte)
postgres(#          GROUP  BY a1_id),
postgres-#      c_cte_agg
postgres-#      AS (SELECT a1_id,
postgres(#                 Sum(field_c1) field_c1_total
postgres(#          FROM   c
postgres(#          WHERE  a1_id IN (SELECT a_cte.id
postgres(#                           FROM   a_cte)
postgres(#          GROUP  BY a1_id)
postgres-# insert into finaldata SELECT a_cte.field_a,
postgres-#        ( b_cte_agg.field_b1_total
postgres(#          + c_cte_agg.field_c1_total ) total_sum
postgres-# FROM   a_cte
postgres-#        LEFT OUTER JOIN b_cte_agg
postgres-#                     ON a_cte.id = b_cte_agg.a1_id
postgres-#        LEFT OUTER JOIN c_cte_agg
postgres-#                     ON a_cte.id = c_cte_agg.a1_id;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=#
```

Final Data:

```
postgres=# select * from finaldata;
 field_a | total_sum
---------+-----------
     100 |       603
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, above query resolve the issue and return desired result but its uses sub query for each master table records that increase load on postgresql server actually in my table there are more than 15 millions of records.

Comment: I have updated the answer with suggestion to make it more performant.